# Key digest for Bridge is wrong length

Tags: configuration, bridge

I am behind college proxy and trying to run a tor daemon on my system.
My torrc configuration is

```
HTTPSProxy 172.30.0.23:3128

UseBridges 1
 # This works for Ubuntu Linux, adjust the path according to your platform
 #ClientTransportPlugin obfs4,obfs3 exec /usr/local/bin/obfs4proxy managed

Bridge obfs4 <bridgeip>:<port> 71C023CF72CAD644FE0FA04C0EA8F840FD562C30 cert=bar8dxwmy5aM/OsRNIUNlLuipQen/NB1w81YhBIGJl89JiqZ+6uih/k4f3VjqjfJ13x4Gw iat-mode=0
```

On running tor daemon using `sudo service tor start` I am getting following error

```
 * Checking if tor configuration is valid
Mar 01 13:11:33.412 [notice] Tor v0.2.4.27 (git-412e3f7dc9c6c01a) running on Linux with Libevent 2.0.21-stable and OpenSSL 1.0.1f.
Mar 01 13:11:33.412 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Mar 01 13:11:33.412 [notice] Read configuration file "/usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults-torrc".
Mar 01 13:11:33.412 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
Mar 01 13:11:33.415 [warn] Key digest for Bridge is wrong length.
Mar 01 13:11:33.415 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Bridge line did not parse. See logs for details.
Mar 01 13:11:33.415 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
```

My college bans tor traffic.

After adding EtorPort auto new config is

```
 HTTPSProxy 172.30.0.23:3128

UseBridges 1
 # This works for Ubuntu Linux, adjust the path according to your platform
 ClientTransportPlugin obfs4,obfs3 exec /usr/local/bin/obfs4proxy managed

ExtORPort auto

Bridge obfs4 <proxy>:<port> 71C023CF72CAD644FE0FA04C0EA8F840FD562C30 cert=bar8dxwmy5aM/OsRNIUNlLuipQen/NB1w81YhBIGJl89JiqZ+6uih/k4f3VjqjfJ13x4Gw iat-mode=0
```

I am getting following error message

```
* Checking if tor configuration is valid
Mar 01 20:55:01.148 [notice] Tor v0.2.4.27 (git-412e3f7dc9c6c01a) running on Linux with Libevent 2.0.21-stable and OpenSSL 1.0.1f.
Mar 01 20:55:01.148 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Mar 01 20:55:01.148 [notice] Read configuration file "/usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults-torrc".
Mar 01 20:55:01.148 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
Mar 01 20:55:01.150 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Unknown option 'ExtORPort'.  Failing.
Mar 01 20:55:01.150 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install obfs4proxy and uncomment the line `ClientTransportPlugin obfs4,obfs3 exec /usr/local/bin/obfs4proxy managed` - it will tell Tor "what is obfs4" bridge backend. It's obviously can't parse the *Bridge* directive - because `obfs4` must be "defined" before used.

UPDATE: You seem to experience a double-proxying case, **this is only a problem in versions of Tor prior to 0.2.6.x**. If you will take a look [here at obfs4 source code](https://github.com/Yawning/obfs4/blob/master/obfs4proxy/proxy_http.go) you will see that it actually understands HTTPS proxy and **this *was* the correct proxy configuration point**, because a pluggable transport is a "proxy" for tor - it wraps it's own communication *through* it in the same manner, that what it is complaining about. So - in your torrc config your line `HTTPSProxy 172.30.0.23:3128` must be commented out. But how to use your proxy *by obfs4*? It uses Go language and the [golang.org/x/net/proxy](https://github.com/golang/net/blob/master/proxy/proxy.go#L29) Dialer in particular, which expects your proxy data to be in the environment. You should set *in your Tor user shell profile * the next lines:

```
export http_proxy=172.30.0.23:3128
export HTTP_PROXY=172.30.0.23:3128
export https_proxy=172.30.0.23:3128
export HTTPS_PROXY=172.30.0.23:3128
```

they are for Bash and Sh, if you're using different shell - please check it's manual

Comment: After uncommenting ClientTransportplugin line I am getting following error  `Mar 01 19:00:16.423 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: You have configured more than one proxy type. (Socks4Proxy|Socks5Proxy|HTTPSProxy|ClientTransportPlugin)`

Comment: I have already installed obfs4proxy. And how to use ExtORPort auto line, it is also giving error. Thanks for your reply. :)

Comment: Add extorport line to your config file - what error it gives you? can you update question with your new config, please?

Comment: Please try the configuration I suggest and let's see what's happen

Comment: After commenting out HTTPSProxy line, my tor daemon is running. Thanks a lot. But ExtORPort auto it was showing same error "Unknown option ExtORPort". But after commenting out ExtORPort line, tor daemon is running. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: you seem to have a **Very** old Tor then, upgdare it - it can contain bugs and vulnerabilities that are already fixed. it's 0.2.9 now - not 0.2.4 !